# how to adds a field and fills in the specified parameters in kafka hisrtory event

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, ksqldb

Now,I have a Topic `PlatformLoginTopic`,Avro schema like this:

```
{
    "namespace": "com.kafka.kafkademo",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "platformLogin",
    "fields": [{
            "name": "id",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "loginName",
            "type": "int"
        },
        {
            "name": "loginTime",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

we counted the number of visitors per day based on loginTime using ksql.

```
Create Stream platformLoginUserStream with (kafka_topic='PlatformLoginTopic',PARTITIONS=1, REPLICAS=1,
value_format='AVRO',TIMESTAMP='loginTime',TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

create table loginTimeStatisticsTable with (KEY_FORMAT='JSON',VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') as
select substring(loginTime,0,10) as loginDate,count(*) as count
from platformLoginUserStream  group by
    substring(loginTime,0,10) emit changes;
```

Then,i insert 5 data.

```
insert into platformLoginUserStream values('2c9a86c57714548c01771961ade60014','Dilpreet Singh','2023-03-02 11:31:40');
insert into platformLoginUserStream values('2c9a86c57714548c017719ba61260058','Jeremy','2023-03-03 13:31:44');
insert into platformLoginUserStream values('2c9a86c677d73bc90177e7bf6cc000d3','Gonzalo Villar','2023-03-03 13:32:45');
insert into platformLoginUserStream values('2c9a86c677d73bc90177e7bf6cc100e6','Jicaar','2023-03-04 10:34:50');
insert into platformLoginUserStream values('2c9a86c57714548c01771961ade60014','Dilpreet Singh','2023-03-04 11:35:40');
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN7fo.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HHW2.png)
Now,We add new fields `platformType` and `platformTypeName` to count the number of visitors to each platform.

```
{
    "namespace": "com.kafka.kafkademo",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "platformLogin",
    "fields": [{
            "name": "id",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "loginName",
            "type": "int"
        },
        {
            "name": "loginTime",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "platformType",
            "type": "int"
        },
        {
            "name": "platformTypeName",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NddX.png)

We need to count not only the events after the field was added, but also the historical events.How do I update the value in the platformType field of the event history based on a rule?

I have tried using Avro defaults to process the data, but historical data is not affected, and Avro defaults do not fill in according to the rules.